# Automate PDF comparison & reporting the differences in another PDF using UFT

Tags: selenium, pdf, comparison, acrobat, hp-uft

Please let me know if it's possible to compare 2 pdf files and store the differences in another pdf using HP UFT or selenium. I was able to achieve comparison of text by copying the data to clipboard,storing it in variable & then using string comparison in UFT but im not sure how to report the differences to PDF. Also let me know if its possible to compare formatting and layout of the pdf files.

Comment: http://www.learnqtp.com/learnquicktestpdf-api-manipulating-pdfs-in-qtp/ has plenty of useful information plus a library you can use

Comment: Thanks Dave. I cannot use the API or download anything from internet due to access restrictions in my company. Is there any other way to do this ? I have tried copying the text from pdf to word & doing word to word comparison & then saving the file to PDF. But was looking for a direct method to do the comparison of text,font & layout. Is there a way to compare two pdfs using Acrobat API?

Comment: Not with the standard setup, you would still need to be able to install an add in I believe.  Seems like you will need to ask for permissions to install, or have someone install the API I mentioned previously for you, or stick with the "copy to text and compare there" method

Comment: I have managed to compare two pdfs using API.However I need to highlight the comparison file differences in blue color. Is there a way to do this using API

Comment: Are you using the API I linked to? Or the Acrobat API directly?

Comment: I'm using the Acrobat API.